# Mongooes Aggregation Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

All dependencies were exported properly. No need to worry about them.

This is the error I get when trying to aggregate:

**Cast to number failed for value "showday" at path "seriesId" for model "Episode"**

**shows.js**

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        var Show = new Schema({
            _id: Number,
            seriesName: String,
            airsDayOfWeek: String,
            airsTime: String,
            firstAired: Date,
            genre: [String],
            network: String,
            overview: String,
            rating: Number,
            ratingCount: Number,
            status: String,
            banner: String,
            poster: String,
            subscribers: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'User'
            }]
        });

        var Show = mongoose.model('Show', Show);
        module.exports = Show;
```

**episode.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var Episode = new Schema({
      _id: Number,
      airedEpisodeNumber: Number,
      airedSeason: Number,
      director: String,
      episodeName: String,
      episodeImage: String,
      firstAired: Date,
      guestStars: [
        String
      ],
      overview: String,
      seriesId: Number,
      writers: [
        String
      ]
  });
    var Episode = mongoose.model('Episode', Episode);
    module.exports = Episode;
```

**episodeRouter.js**

```
    episodeRouter.route('/showday')
            .get(function(req, res, next){
                var result = [];
                var today = new Date().toISOString();

                result = Episode.aggregate([
                            {$match: {firstAired: today}},
                            {$sort: {rating: -1}},
                            {$lookup: {
                                localField: seriesId,
                                from: shows,
                                foreignField: _id,
                                as: "showInfo"
                            }},
                            {$unwind: "$showInfo"},
                            {$project: {
                                firstAired: 1,
                                airedSeason: 1,
                                airedEpisodeNumber: 1,
                                "$showInfo.seriesName": 1,
                                "$showInfo.poster": 1
                            }}
                        ], function(err, data) {
                    // if any error exist, move to the next middleware function
                    if (err) next(err);
                    // write result to the response as json
                    res.json(data);
                });
            });
```

Comment: You mean something like `seriesName: "$showInfo.seriesName"` in the project. You have the variable on the wrong side. The value is on the "right" and you put it on the "left".

Comment: "Both" places where you incorrectly use the `$` prefixed variables on the "left hand side".

Comment: "$showInfo.seriesName": 1 is as per mongodb documentation

Comment: The [actual documentation says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-computed-fields) `{ $project: { lastName: "$author.last" } }` and not  `{ $project: { "$author.last": 1 } }` which is your error here. Read the actual page.

Comment: I changed it. but problem still exists

Comment: `{$project: { firstAired: 1,airedSeason: 1,                               airedEpisodeNumber: 1, seriesName: "$showInfo.seriesName", poster: "$showInfo.poster" }}` Just copy and paste. Then spend 20 minutes looking at the documentation more carefully to understand why that is correct.

Comment: That is what I did which didn't work

Comment: No you have not done that because that is exactly what works for the rest of the people in the word.

Comment: {$project: {
                            firstAired: 1,
                            airedSeason: 1,
                            airedEpisodeNumber: 1,
                            seriesName: "$showInfo.seriesName",
                            poster: "$showInfo.poster"
                        }}

Comment: Then you are also doing something else wrong here. There is something happening in code you are not listing. The big bold error in your question suggests that you are trying to feed values into a new mongoose model instance. That would be another completely incorrect thing to do. The aggregation pipeline ( with those corrections ) is fine by itself. Simply run the same thing in the mongo shell. Your error is elsewhere.